# k-means using word2vec : Find nearest words to centroids

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, k-means, word2vec

I am using word2vec for vectorization of texts and then k-means for clustering of texts using scikit-learn. After clustering, how do I get the top 5 or 10 words nearest to the centroid of each cluster? I am able to get all the words in the cluster but not able to get the nearest words. It was straight-forward when I was using tf-idf vectorizer as each feature in tf-idf maps to a word, but it is not the case with word2vec

Here's how I am using word2vec for k-means

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('w2v.mdel')
word_vectors =  vecTransform(input) #Convert input text to word vectors
km = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
idx = km.fit_predict(word_vectors)
```

Comment: It really depends on how you use word2vec to vectorize the text. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @geompalik I have added my code now

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is `vecTransform` that matters. If for a given text document, you are averaging over the w2v representations of the words it contains to get the document representation, you are still in a space of the same dimension as the initial w2v vectors. Hence, given the centroids of the k-means algorithm (`km.cluster_centers_` as you seem to use the `sklearn` implementation), you can find the closest words to those centroids.. However, I am sure how meaningful they can be, especially if the documents contain several words and you use all of the to the averaging process.

Comment: Yes. I am averaging all the w2v of all words in a document. Can you please suggest a better approach?

Comment: A priori this would be another question. Compositionality in embeddings is not a solved problem in my opinion. I have yet to understand what you are trying to achieve though.